# Error "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in jsOAuth

Tags: oauth, xmlhttprequest, twitter, cross-domain, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to use the twitter API with library [jsOAuth](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth).

### Full html

```
<div id="message">Loading..</div>

<script src="jsOAuth-1.3.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var oauth = OAuth({
            consumerKey: "-MY-KEY-",
            consumerSecret: "MY-SECRET"
        });
```

**Updated**
            oauth.get("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json?callback=?", success, failure);

```
        function success(data){
            $("#message").html("Sucess: " + data.text);
            var timeline = jQuery.parseJSON(data.text);
            console.log(timeline);
            $.each(timeline, function (element){
                console.log(element.text);
            });
        }
        function failure(data) {
            console.log("Throw rotten fruit, something failed");
            $("#message").html("Error" );
        }   
</script>
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

[Full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5oQe.png)

### Questions

- What am I doing wrong?
- How can I use the twitter API in my PC.

If you can send me I would appreciate any examples.

**Thank you all.**

Answer (score 4):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are trying to make an AJAX request to Twitter. You are violating cross domain access policies - you cannot access data on the Twitter domain.

> How can I use the Twitter API on my PC?

Pick one :

- Use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)
- Use a server-side proxy
- *Store your code on a `file://` path, which removes the cross domain restrictions*
- *Change your browser's security settings to allow this kind of access.*

I have styled the unlikely ones in italic.

Also, as an experienced Twitter developer, I have one important note to make about your code: you're using Javascript to access the API. While using JS to do that isn't disallowed, using OAuth in javascript is very unsafe and your application *will* be blocked from the Twitter API if you used this code on a website.

Comment: I'm using "JS" for studies only, in my real application will not be this way.

I modified the code to use JSONP (still did not work).  

Sorry, I did not understand: "Use a server-side proxy" You mean to publish the file on an IIS server (for example)?

Comment: How do I change the browser settings to allow this kind of access? Thanks for your help

Comment: Most browsers allow you to change this on the security pane. I'm sorry but I can't be more specific. With using a server-side proxy I mean writing a script that simply makes the requests for you, but from the server. AJAX *will* allow you to make requests to the domain you're browsing on. JSONP should work fine in your case - if it didn't work in your case then you didn't implement it correctly.

Comment: I published the code at the following address: http://ridermansb.kodingen.com/Rest-JSOAuth.html

Comment: Thought so - that's no JSONP.

Comment: Could provide me more details?
I made some modifications to the code, see: [http://ridermansb.kodingen.com/Rest-JSOAuth.html].  

I do not know what to do if you can give me some example

Comment: Sorry, 404 address.
New: ridermansb.kodingen.com/Rest-JSOAuth.html

Comment: The answer is excellent, and correct, and contains entry points for further reading on your own part. Read up on JSONP, there are loads of resources on that. For example: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/twitter-jsonjsonp-api-url.html

Comment: Also, if you DO want to do ajax calls to violating cross domain polices, there are ways in which you can disable web security in your browser. Hint for chrome: --disable-web-security

Comment: The answer is correct. jsOAuth wasn't designed to be used in browsers.